# vue.js input function call | Samsung s9 device | function not calling

Tags: android, vue.js, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

scenario is after typing 3 characters function should call. It working in desktop and other devices. But in Samsung device it's not working. It working after enter the space or close the mobile keyboard.
My expectation is: Function should call after typed 3 characters
Below is .vue file

```
<input id="searchInput" v-model="searchString" @input="searchString.length>=3 && showSearchResults($event)" @keyup="searchString.length>=3 && showSearchResults($event)">
```

Below is js file

```
showSearchResults {
  // some function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to check for length inside function?

```
<input id="searchInput" v-model="searchString" @input='onInput'">
```

```
methods: {
  onInput(value) {
    // if length less than 3 do nothing
    if(value.length <=3) return
    enter code here
  }
}
```